# jQuery get value from while loop and display it in another div without click

Tags: php, jquery

How do I make jQuery get value from while loop and display it in another div?

I know I should do it with PHP, But I want to display it with only jQuery.

```
<? while($commentresult = $commentdata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>

    <div class="show_url"></div>
    <a href="<? echo $commentresult['comment']; ?>" class="get_url_comments" target="_blank"></a>

<? } ?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var getUrl = $('.get_url_comments').attr('href');
    $(".show_url").text("Click This" + getUrl);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked your console to see if there's any errors?

Comment: use html() function instead of text()

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/farazadeo/sqxwqt11/

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can set the `text()` of the `.show_url` element based on the following `.get_url_comments`. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show_url").text(function() {
        return $(this).next('.get_url_comments').attr('href');
    });
});
```

You should note though that it would be a *much* better idea to do this directly in PHP:

```
<? while($commentresult = $commentdata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <div class="show_url"><? echo $commentresult['comment']; ?></div>
    <a href="<? echo $commentresult['comment']; ?>" class="get_url_comments" target="_blank"></a>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this. Could you please check my code?
[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/o8m3dnk3/)

I got an error on this line `var extracted_id_yt = extracted_url.match(match_youtube_id)[1];`

And in console log `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.get_url_comments').map(function(guc){
         var el = $(guc);
         var url = el.attr('href');
         el.prev().text("Click This" + url);
         // or
         el.prev().html("Click This" + url);
    });
});
```